# Vuetify - Use SCSS to change or prepend to class names

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I've created a web component using Vue2 & Vuetify2 and it's working almost flawlessly bar a few websites where there are CSS clashes.

The problem is that the web component is not in a shadowDOM and as much as I've tried getting this to work, it just doesn't (seems the issue lies with Vuetify + shadowDOM).

As an alternative, would it be possible to change or prepend to class names to stop CSS conflicts?

For example `row` is a typically used class name. Would it be possible to prepend either `widget`, `.widget` or `#widget` to all other classes & id's?

[Demo](https://boodil-demo.pages.dev/cart) of the widget.

Comment: Unfortunately, it it not possible to customize vuetify class names. You'll have to find another way to fix your initial issue.

Comment: Hi @Kapcash, would it not be possible to scope Vuetify's CSS names so that only apply if a set parent class is present. For example, instead of '.row', have '#widget .row'.